# Connect to AWS IOT MQTT

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot

Trying to connect to AWS IOT MQTT server with MQTT explorer client. Client is trying to connect, but fails.

I have certificate and key files from AWS that I set in connection settings:

```
Server certificate (CA) - AmazonRootCA1.pem
Client certificate - 6de1c9d4f67f738f68bb989250cc80f96ed28b3f617de402d317a0e28552aaaf-certificate.pem.crt
Client key - 6de1c9d4f67f738f68bb989250cc80f96ed28b3f617de402d317a0e28552aaaf-public.pem.key 
Not used - 6de1c9d4f67f738f68bb989250cc80f96ed28b3f617de402d317a0e28552aaaf-private.pem.key
```

Other settings:

```
Protocol mqtt
host : a3cnel9blokaaa-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
port : 8883
encryption: tls
validate certificate : true
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing, based on the filenames, that you are using the public key when the private key is required.

Comment: Got the same result after setting file with private key.

Comment: Then without more details about how it has failed we are unlikely to be able to say any more.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/thomasnordquist/MQTT-Explorer/issues/194) for some possible causes/solutions.

Comment: @vico, do you have an iot policy attached to your certificate. Also, what clientId are you using when connecting to aws iot core?

Answer (score 1):

As @Brits pointed out in the comments, when using Certificates to identify a client you need to make use of the private key to sign the request, not the public key.

This is because with public/private key crytography the public key is what you distribute to the world (hence public) so everybody else can verify that you (and only you) have access to the private key.

Comment: Got the same result after setting file with private key.